# vs code c/c++ debugging gets stuck, it only shows running in call stack and does not show any variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

VS Code C/C++ debugging gets stuck, it only shows running in call stack and does not show any variables please help i am new to this.

This is my launch.json file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": 
[

{
    "name": "(Windows) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/return0.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false
},

]
```

**This is my code for sum of two Numbers saved as return0.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    {
     int a,b,c;
     printf("Enter two No.\n");
     scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
     c=a+b;
     printf("the sum is %d",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need precisions on what you expect. What do you mean by "gets stuck"?

Comment: what is the need for the braces inside `main()`